# Display only duplicates from a UNION ALL query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that gathers usernames from 4 UNIONS. How do I display only the duplicate users from that result? (ideally only displaying each duplicate once).

Thanks!

Here is the query:

```
(SELECT user1 AS user FROM   friendships WHERE  user2 = 'johnsmith') 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT user2 AS user FROM   friendships WHERE  user1 = 'johnsmith') 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT user1 AS user FROM   friendships WHERE  user2 = 'johndoe') 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT user2 AS user FROM   friendships WHERE  user1 = 'johndoe')
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
SELECT user
FROM ((SELECT user1 AS user 
       FROM friendships 
       WHERE user2 = 'johnsmith' 
      ) UNION ALL 
      (SELECT user2 AS user 
       FROM friendships 
       WHERE user1 = 'johnsmith' 
      ) UNION ALL 
      (SELECT user1 AS user 
       FROM friendships 
       WHERE user2 = 'johndoe')
      ) UNION ALL 
      (SELECT user2 AS user 
       FROM friendships 
       WHERE user1 = 'johndoe'
      ) 
     ) u
GROUP BY user
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

You can probably express this so it does only one pass over the data:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN user1 = 'johnsmith' THEN user2
             WHEN user2 = 'johnsmith' THEN user1
             WHEN user1 = 'johndoe' THEN user2
             WHEN user2 = 'johndoe' THEN user1
        END) as user
FROM friendships f
WHERE 'johnsmith' in (user1, user2) or 'johndoe' in (user1, user2)
GROUP BY user
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Note that this is not *exactly* the same.  It would count a friendship between `'johnsmith'` and `'johndoe'` only once.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT user, count(*) FROM (
(SELECT user1 AS user FROM   friendships WHERE  user2 = 'johnsmith') 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT user2 AS user FROM   friendships WHERE  user1 = 'johnsmith') 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT user1 AS user FROM   friendships WHERE  user2 = 'johndoe') 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT user2 AS user FROM   friendships WHERE  user1 = 'johndoe') ) x
GROUP BY user
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

USE `GROUP BY` AND `HAVING`

Comment: i think it should be 'user' not 'user1' on the `select` and `group by` clauses

Comment: Oh didnt notice his 'as user'. Updated!